# How to call child function without calling the parent one

Tags: javascript

I had an interview in javascript. Interviewer asked me the following question when i am explaining the concept of "Closure".Actually need to invoke the child method in outside without calling the parent method. Is it possible? I am unable understand the intention of the question. Anybody let me know if it is possible

```
function parent(){ 
    console.log("you called parent function")
    function  child(){
      console.log("child");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't be done. Think about it. How can you be here, if your parents weren't here first? The parent has to be called, at least once.

Comment: This can't be done. `child` is undefined anywhere but in the midst of a call to `parent`.

Comment: it is logically impossible to call a function which is inside a function, without calling the outer function. and i dont think that is what they asked you

Comment: @AhmedKhattab - Oh, I can totally see this as an interview question, trying to get the OP to explain why you have to call `parent`, to demonstrate their understanding of scope, and possibly to get them to expand on that a bit as in the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to call the `child` function without *ever* calling the `parent` function, no; the `child` function doesn't exist until/unless the `parent` function is called. (Also note that it creates a *different* `child` function every time it's called.)

However, if you modify `parent` so that it *returns* the `child` function it creates...

```
function parent(){ 
    console.log("");
    return function  child(){
//  ^^^^^^
      console.log("child");
   };
}
```

...you can call `parent` once and then call `child` as many times as you like:

```
const c = parent(); // "you called parent function"
c();                // "child"
c();                // "child"
c();                // "child"
```

Comment: This sounds like the intent of the interviewer!

Comment: @Gershom - Yeah, that's my suspicion too.

Comment: I feel that too.. But anyway I was selected on that interview.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

The scope of the `child` name is just the `parent` function. The only way to get a reference to the `child` function from outside is to call `parent()` and have it return the function, e.g.

```js
function parent(){ 
    console.log("you called parent function")
    function child(){
      console.log("child");
    }
    return child;
}
var c = parent();
c();
```

There's no syntax in JavaScript for directly accessing variables local to a function from outside the function.